# How to prove an asymptotic formula for the number of distinct prime factors of an integer $n$?

Tags: nt.number-theory

I can show that the sum of $\omega(j)$ over all $j\leq n$ is $nloglogn+bn+O(\frac{n}{log n}$).  However, what I need is that $\sum(\omega(j)-loglogn)^2$ with sum over all $j\leq n=$ O$(nloglogn)$. Can anyone provide a route to the solution? It'll be highly appreciated.

Comment: same OP, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/918901/how-to-prove-an-asymptotic-formula-for-the-number-of-distinct-prime-factors-of-a

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the first results of Paul Turán. See Theorem 2.12 and its proof in Montgomery-Vaughan: Multiplicative number theory I. Alternately, see Theorem 430 and its proof in Hardy-Wright: An introduction to the theory of numbers.